# Still getting link error after switching to banked memory for Freescale HCS08

Tags: freescale, hcs08

My program for a Freescale MC9S08DZ128 (HCS08 family) got too big, and I was getting the message:

```
Link Error   : L1102: Out of allocation space in segment ROM2 at address 0xFE13
```

so I tried to switch to the banked memory model.

My options before I switched were:

```
-Cs08 -Fd -Ms -OnB=b -TD2LD2LLD2
```

and my options afterwards are:

```
-Cs08 -Fd -Mb -MMU -OnB=b -TD2LD2LLD2
```

I also changed my library from ansifs.lib to ansibfm.lib

But after doing this (and recompiling everything), I still get the same linker error as I did before, implying it is still out of memory.  Any idea why it is not making use of the banked memory in my device?  It has 128K of Flash memory.

I am using version 6.3 of Code Warrior (Classic IDE, Basic Edition, code & data limited to 128K).

Here is the .prm file showing the banked segments (PPAGE_)

```
/* This is a linker parameter file for the mc9s08dz128 */

NAMES END /* CodeWarrior will pass all the needed files to the linker by command line. But here you may add your own files too. */

SEGMENTS /* Here all RAM/ROM areas of the device are listed. Used in PLACEMENT below. */
    Z_RAM                    =  READ_WRITE   0x0080 TO 0x00FF;
    RAM                      =  READ_WRITE   0x0100 TO 0x17FF;
    RAM1                     =  READ_WRITE   0x1900 TO 0x217F;
    /* unbanked FLASH ROM */
    ROM                      =  READ_ONLY    0x4000 TO 0x7FFF;
    /*ROM1                     =  READ_ONLY    0x2180 TO 0x3BFF;*/
    ROM1                     =  READ_ONLY    0x2200 TO 0x3BFF;  /* changed due to code gen error at 0x2180 when code size >= 0x6000 */    
    ROM2                     =  READ_ONLY    0xC000 TO 0xFF7F;
    EEPROM                   =  READ_ONLY    0x3C00 TO 0x3FFF;
 /* INTVECTS                 =  READ_ONLY    0xFF80 TO 0xFFFF; Reserved for Interrupt Vectors */
    /* banked FLASH ROM */
    PPAGE_0                  =  READ_ONLY    0x008000 TO 0x00A17F; /* PAGE partially contained in ROM segment */
    PPAGE_0_1                =  READ_ONLY    0x00BC00 TO 0x00BFFF; 
    PPAGE_2                  =  READ_ONLY    0x028000 TO 0x02BFFF; 
    PPAGE_4                  =  READ_ONLY    0x048000 TO 0x04BFFF; 
    PPAGE_5                  =  READ_ONLY    0x058000 TO 0x05BFFF; 
    PPAGE_6                  =  READ_ONLY    0x068000 TO 0x06BFFF; 
    PPAGE_7                  =  READ_ONLY    0x078000 TO 0x07BFFF; 
 /* PPAGE_1                  =  READ_ONLY    0x018000 TO 0x01BFFF; PAGE already contained in segment at 0x4000-0x7FFF */
 /* PPAGE_3                  =  READ_ONLY    0x038000 TO 0x03BFFF; PAGE already contained in segment at 0xC000-0xFFFF */
END

PLACEMENT /* Here all predefined and user segments are placed into the SEGMENTS defined above. */
    DEFAULT_RAM,                        /* non-zero page variables */
                                        INTO  RAM,RAM1;

    _PRESTART,                          /* startup code */
    STARTUP,                            /* startup data structures */
    ROM_VAR,                            /* constant variables */
    STRINGS,                            /* string literals */
    VIRTUAL_TABLE_SEGMENT,              /* C++ virtual table segment */
    NON_BANKED,                         /* runtime routines which must not be banked */
    DEFAULT_ROM,
    COPY                                /* copy down information: how to initialize variables */
                                        INTO  ROM,ROM1,ROM2; /* ,ROM1,ROM2: To use "ROM1,ROM2" as well, pass the option -OnB=b to the compiler */

    PAGED_ROM                           /* routines which can be banked */
                                        INTO  PPAGE_0,PPAGE_0_1,PPAGE_2,PPAGE_4,PPAGE_5,PPAGE_6,PPAGE_7,ROM1,ROM2;

    _DATA_ZEROPAGE,                     /* zero page variables */
    MY_ZEROPAGE                         INTO  Z_RAM;
END

STACKSIZE 0x200

VECTOR 0 _Startup /* Reset vector: this is the default entry point for an application. */
```

and the beginning of the .map file showing the banked object file (.o) under the FILE SECTION:

```
*********************************************************************************************
STARTUP SECTION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

*********************************************************************************************
SECTION-ALLOCATION SECTION
Section Name                    Size  Type     From       To       Segment
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.data                             70   R/W      0x100      0x145   RAM
.init                            138     R     0x4000     0x4089   ROM
.startData                        18     R     0x408A     0x409B   ROM
.rodata                         2596     R     0x409C     0x4ABF   ROM
.rodata1                        1697     R     0x4AC0     0x5160   ROM
.text                          11910     R     0x5161     0x7FE6   ROM

***************************************************************************************

    ******
    TARGET SECTION
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Processor   : Freescale HC08
    Memory Model: BANKED
    File Format : ELF (no debug info)
    Linker      : SmartLinker V-5.0.37 Build 9279, Oct  7 2009

    *********************************************************************************************
    FILE SECTION
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    main.c.o                                Model: BANKED,        Lang: ANSI-C
    Analog.c.o                              Model: BANKED,        Lang: ANSI-C
    Character_Library_for_Dot_Matrix_LCD.c.oModel: BANKED,        Lang: ANSI-C
    MC9S08DZ128.C.o                         Model: BANKED,        Lang: ANSI-C
    Start08.c.o                             Model: BANKED,        Lang: ANSI-C
    Menu.c.o                                Model: BANKED,        Lang: ANSI-C
    IIC.c.o                                 Model: BANKED,        Lang: ANSI-C
    eeprom.c.o                              Model: BANKED,        Lang: ANSI-C
    LCD-NHD-C12865AR.c.o                    Model: BANKED,        Lang: ANSI-C
    LCD.c.o                                 Model: BANKED,        Lang: ANSI-C
    time.c.o                                Model: BANKED,        Lang: ANSI-C
    functions.c.o                           Model: BANKED,        Lang: ANSI-C
    input_data.c.o                          Model: BANKED,        Lang: ANSI-C
    recording.c.o                           Model: BANKED,        Lang: ANSI-C
    CTYPE.C.o (ansibfm.lib)                 Model: BANKED,        Lang: ANSI-C
    MATH08F.C.o (ansibfm.lib)               Model: BANKED,        Lang: ANSI-C
    PRINTF.C.o (ansibfm.lib)                Model: BANKED,        Lang: ANSI-C
    RTSHC08.C.o (ansibfm.lib)               Model: BANKED,        Lang: ANSI-C
    STDLIB.C.o (ansibfm.lib)                Model: BANKED,        Lang: ANSI-C
    STRING.C.o (ansibfm.lib)                Model: BANKED,        Lang: ANSI-C

    *********************************************************************************************
    STARTUP SECTION
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    *********************************************************************************************
    SECTION-ALLOCATION SECTION
    Section Name                    Size  Type     From       To       Segment
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .data                             71   R/W      0x100      0x146   RAM
    .init                            139     R     0x4000     0x408A   ROM
    .startData                        18     R     0x408B     0x409C   ROM
    .rodata                         2596     R     0x409D     0x4AC0   ROM
    .rodata1                        1697     R     0x4AC1     0x5161   ROM
    NON_BANKED                      3008     R     0x5162     0x5D21   ROM
    .text                           8215     R     0x5D22     0x7D38   ROM
```

Comment: There are a few reasons this could be happening. Did you try the suggestions here? http://www.embeddedrelated.com/groups/68hc12/show/16761.php

Comment: @travis Although similar, that forum post is for an HCS12, not an HCS08,, so the suggest about uncommenting ROM_4000 doesn't apply.  I'm already including the -OnB=b option as shown in my question above

Comment: Seems as though the DEFAULT section is referring to ROM rather than PAGED_ROM, so all code is placed in the wrong section.  Not sure why this would occur with your configuration though.  http://www.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/app_note/AN3730.pdf page 10 may give some ideas.  Perhaps try manually adding `#pragma CODE_SEG PAGED_ROM` around some functions and see if these functions end up in the `PAGED_ROM` section rather than `.text`.

Comment: @AustinPhillips Although Freescale finally came back to me with a proper .prm file, which fixed my linker issue, I was not aware of the PDF document you linked to -- if I had that, I would probably have been able to figure this out for myself.  Make your comment an answer so I can give you the 500 point bonus -- I hate to see it expire and not go to someone.

Comment: @tcrosley I don't think my comment constitutes a good enough answer to your question.  Perhaps you could write an answer with the the correct .prm file contents for comparison and explain why the original linker script was incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of paging requires co-operation between both the compiler and linker to work correctly.  The following application note from Freescale has a lot of information about how paging works and the appropriate options to pass to the compiler and linker.

http://www.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/app_note/AN3730.pdf

It seems as though the compiler may be placing code in the wrong segment for paging to work.  The .prm file listed expects paged object code to exist in the `PAGED_ROM` segment, the linker will then distribute the code through to each of the `PPAGE_0,PPAGE_0_1,PPAGE_2...` etc pages.

I would try experimenting by manually adding `#pragma CODE_SEG PAGED_ROM` around some functions and see if these functions end up in the `PAGED_ROM` section rather than `ROM` section.